# How to get 2 different sections from web.config using one base ConfigurationSection class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web-config

I need to get data from `viewModelSettings` section in web.config

```
<vmSettings namespace="Site.Web.ViewModels" assembly="Site.Web"/>
```

and to be able to get namespace like this **VM.Settings.Namespace VM2.Settings.Namespace**

I created the following class, so I could use it like `VM.Settings.Namespace`

```
public class VM : ConfigurationSection
    {
        private static VM _settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("vmSettings") as VM;

        public static VM Settings
        {
            get { return _settings; }
        }  

   [ConfigurationProperty("namespace", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Namespace
        {
            get
            {                
                return (string)base["namespace"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("assembly", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Assembly
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base["assembly"];
            }
        }        
    }
```

Now, I have another section(**vmSettings2**) the same as the above one but with different name
`<vmSettings2 namespace="Site2.Web.ViewModels" assembly="Site2.Web"/>`

I didn't want to write another ConfigurationSection class but use the above one(but it should get **vmSettings2** section) and use it like VM2.Settings.Namespace. How could I implement this? Maybe inherit from VM class, but how to override the section name?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not convert your VM class into an abstract base class?

Then you could derive two classes from that called vmSettings1 and vmSettings2 which would simply use the methods defined in the base class?

You could possibly use VM as an interface but then you'd be forced to implement each method for each class which is possibly the type of thing you're hoping to avoid here.

Comment: But, how to override static properties? can you give me example so I still could use it like VM1.Settings.Namespace VM2.Settings.Namespace

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public class VM : ConfigurationSection
    {

        public static VM GetSection(string section)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.GetSection(section) as VM;
        }  

        [ConfigurationProperty("namespace", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Namespace
        {
            get
            {                
                return (string)base["namespace"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("assembly", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Assembly
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base["assembly"];
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: but i want to be able to use get namespace in this way VM1.Settings.Namespace VM2.Settings.Namespace